# jquery types not available in external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following in my theme.js file:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  accordion($)
})

const accordion = ($) => ...
```

When I write the accordion function directly into the jQuery function Typescript will assist with the installed jquery type declarations. When the markup is like the above I do not get type support in my accordion function.

Is there any way to fix this?

Edit: I should also mention that typescript support for the js file is coming from VS Code

Comment: Hello Hewe, yeah, you added the edit, wanted to ask you about that. You can either add typescript to the project, or, if that's not the option you can use the type system from VSCode, I'll show you in an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, since your project doesn't use typescript in the context of `const accordion = ($)` the `$` gets implicit any, since VSCode can't assume it's actually jQuery.

There are 2 options to make the type system bend to your needs, either by adding typescript to your project, or:

```js
/**
 * @param {JQuery} $ - the jquery instance
 */
const accordion = ($) => {

};
```

This special syntax is called a `jsblock`, and it allows intelisense features to non-typescript projects.

That should make VSCode recognize the `$` type and trigger the intelisense.

Comment: Would I have to include the jsblock for every 'external' function referenced in the initial jquery function or just once outside of it?

Comment: You would have to include a JS block for every function that has implicit `any`. If you mouse over the argument, and you see the type systems reporting "any" that means you have to assign a type with either TypeScript or with a jsblock

Comment: I explored the jsblock docs and started looking through the TS docs as well for a solution to only have to declare this once vs for every function, to no avail. Do you know of any solution for this?